# How to clean pip installed packages on MacOSX?

Tags: python, macos, pip

I try to remove all pip installed packages from MacOSX. Following zsh loop removed most of them, but some resists.

```
for i ($(pip freeze )) {pip uninstall -y $i}
```

For example matlibplot hasn't been removed. When I try to run uninstall it find matplotlib, print related paths, but fails.

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
Uninstalling matplotlib-1.3.1:
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7.egg-info
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pylab.py
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pylab.pyc
Proceed (y/n)?
```

I got following very long error message. It seems that files cannot be removed. Error sample:

```
error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/__init__.py', '/tmp/pip-PK6UUB-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-PK6UUB-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/__init__.py'"),
```

What should I do?

To make clear, commands are run from root account. Pip can find package metadata:

```
pip show matplotlib
---
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: matplotlib
Version: 1.3.1
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: http://matplotlib.org 
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: mdroe@stsci.edu
License: BSD
Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Requires: numpy, python-dateutil, tornado, pyparsing, nose
Classifiers:
  Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable
  Intended Audience :: Science/Research
  License :: OSI Approved :: Python Software Foundation License
  Programming Language :: Python
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3
  Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Visualization
```

Comment: Run as root or sudo.

Comment: I ran all above as root.

Comment: I moved the question to AskDiffrent: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235041/how-to-clean-pip-installed-packages-on-macosx/235050#235050 because my problem seems to be MacOSX specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that matplotlib still shows when you run

```
$ pip freeze
```

I'm not that familiar with the OSX environment but I'll try to adapt as much as possible from the Linux/GNU environment. First of all, are you able to reinstall matplotlib with the command:

```
$ pip install pysqlite
```

It should return something like this if pip assumes that it is already installed

```
 Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib in PATH
```

Using this returned path, go to `PATH/dist-packages/matlibplot*.egg/` (or anywhere else you store your eggs in your python path) and look for the `installed-files.txt` file. If it does not exist, pip won't be able to uninstall the package.

The manual alternative is therefore to remove all the files within that egg path and you're rid of matplotlib. You may also have to edit the `easy-install.*` file in the `dist-packages` directory and remove the matplotlib entry from it, so that `pip freeze` commands stops showing it up.

Comment: Interesting idea, however I think the problem is one MacOSX side. Also pip show matplotlib seems to be good enough to get package information - including path.